# Why my git svn with error "dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _svn_ra_make_callbacks"

Tags: git-svn

I got this problem when I use git svn to checkout my svn repos.Then I follow some suggestions from website and try to reinstall svn:core by

```
sudo cpan SVN:Core
```

but I still got following error when I try to check out a svn repos.

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _svn_ra_make_callbacks
Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.32.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.32.0/darwin-thread- 
multi-2level/auto/SVN/_Ra/_Ra.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _svn_ra_make_callbacks
Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.32.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.32.0/darwin-thread- 
multi-2level/auto/SVN/_Ra/_Ra.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace

error: git-svn died of signal 6
```

I check from website that the function is declared in the library header:

```
libsvn_swig_perl/swigutil_pl.h
```

But I didn't find error message related this lib (I did see some warning) when I install SVN:Core.
Are there something I need to setup or check for this issue when I install SVN:Core to make my git svn check out work properly?

Thank you~~

Eric

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to manually install Perl package `SVN::Core`. The [Homebrew formula `subversion`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/e99bc3365e9bb18bd75373b417176c1078d0fcae/Formula/subversion.rb#L135-L161) already does that — but, only for Intel hardware currently, as you can see. Volunteering to contribute other hardware support would be warmly welcome.

That *formula* (script) is what powers `brew install subversion`. Does this command work for you at all? Can you run `svn info`? If not, then you should first of all get `svn` installation working — and only then add `git-svn` on top. This is because the dependency structure looks like this:

[image: graphviz dot graph with 4 nodes]

If the bottom-most box is broken for you, then messing with Perl packages is guaranteed to not help.

---

> I check from website that the function is declared in the library header

Please be specific; which website? I don't see any `_svn_ra_make_callbacks` in the [latest upstream source](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/libsvn_swig_perl/swigutil_pl.h), neither in [1.14.1 tarball](https://archive.apache.org/dist/subversion/subversion-1.14.1.tar.bz2).

Comment: I search from website and found following link that have this function's declaration.

http://www1.udel.edu/CIS/software/svn/dist/subversion-1.4.4/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/libsvn_swig_perl/swigutil_pl.h

https://github.com/jmckaskill/subversion/blob/master/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/libsvn_swig_perl/swigutil_pl.c

Comment: If I check out the svn repos directly, then the svn info work for me. But if I use git svn clone to check out the repos, then I got the error above and svn doesn't work on my target directory.

Comment: @彭煥閎 so `svn` works, but `git-svn` doesn't? Interesting. How did you install `git`? Did you make sure to clean out all remnants of `git` and make a clean install from known-good state?

Comment: Also notice the versions. Your link to `udel.edu` lists source code for svn **`1.4.4`** — while the latest is **`1.14.1`**. There's no function called `_svn_ra_make_callbacks` in the latest version. Perhaps it was removed long ago.

Comment: I just use brew uninstall git, brew install git to reinstall git. Should I use other way to reinstall git again? about the _svn_ra_make_callbacks is the old version function, is that mean I have some old git svn in my desktop? My git version is 2.31.1, and svn: 1.14.1, git svn: git-svn version 2.31.1 (svn 1.8.11), the svn version in git svn didn't match my current svn version, it that might the possible problem?

Comment: @彭煥閎 yes, that mismatch indicates the problem. I guess `git-svn` picks a wrong installation of `subversion`, or perhaps tries to install its own. As the way forward, I'd recommend looking carefully into the [Homebrew Formula](https://formulae.brew.sh) for `git`/`git-svn` and try to isolate the issue by reproducing `brew install git` step-by-step from source.